# Could I use a SQL CE 4 database to build a company website with a blog?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I cannot figure out how to deploy website with SQL Server Express so could I use SQL CE 4 instead?  I've chosen [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) as CMS.

Answer (score 1):

SQL CE is not meant for multi user access.  SQL Express (or higher) will work fine.  What problems are you having with SQL Express.

Comment: Connection string and can not see database.mdf file in App_Data. Arvixe is my website hoster and database system is there strange

Comment: SQL Server Compact 4.0 supports ASP.NET!

Comment: but can i use sq; server compact in multi user environment

Comment: IMO, SQL CE is perfectly targeted towards use as an embedded, single user database. It may now support multiple connection (I think as of 3.5?) but it will not scale up.

Comment: I just checked the arvixe.com site and it states they support "unlimited MS SQL 2008" databases.  It is really a question for them to give you guidence how to setup and configure them.  Do they let the DB sit on the web host (ick) or do they have dedicated DB servers you connect to>

Comment: DB sit on the web host. I think i get rid of idea using sql express. soon i forget also asp.net and return to my old php friend. because of c# i've started to use asp.net, but website deployment is nightmare